# Riverpod StateNotifierProvider with autoDispose throw an error "Invalid argument: Maximum call stack size exceeded" on FLUTTER WEB

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

StateNotifierProvider with autodispose run on android, but on flutter web its throw this error :

[image]

Can't we call the autodispose func on StateNotifierProvider ?

How to reproduce the error :

create a state notifier provider with `autoDispose` :

```
final homeControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<HomeController, HomeState>(
        (ref) => HomeController(ref));
```

and call it inside ConsumerWidget :

```
class Home extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // this line throw this error
    final status = ref.watch(homeControllerProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(status.data.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

StateNotifier class :

```
class HomeController extends StateNotifier<HomeState> {
  HomeController(this.ref) : super(const HomeState()) ;
  final Ref ref;

  void changeData(String data) {
    state = state.copyWith(data: data);
  }

}
```

State class :

```
class HomeState {
  const HomeState({this.data = 'hello world'});
  final String data;

  HomeState copyWith({String? data}) => HomeState(data: data ?? this.data);
}
```

when i remove the `autoDispose`, the error gone.
the doc say `autoDispose` destroy the state of a provider when it is no-longer used. lets say i need to destroy this state provider or reset it state later, how to work around this, i am new to riverpod, please help

Comment: It's a known Dart bug. A workaround will be released in 2.1.0. Either wait for that new version or use a lower Riverpod version

Comment: @RémiRousselet thanks for response, i am your fan <3, riverpod is beautiful just like flutter. is there a way to dispose other than autodispose, "manually"?